# Genymotion 2.1.0 + GApps

Tags: android, genymotion

After I've updated Genymotion to 2.1.0 I couldn't install GApps with drag and drop, someone had this problem? There is another way to install GApps on Genymotion?

**Update**
I just cleared the cache and it's worked again.

Settings > Misc > Cache usage > Clear cache